# Require a possibly nullable generic to be not null

Tags: generics, kotlin

In Kotlin I'm able to write a function which takes a generic possibly nullable argument from a super class - let's call it `Person` - and returns the exact same type like this:

```
fun <V: Person?> identity(arg1: V): V = arg1

val p1: Person? = identity(null) // works fine
val p2: Person = identity(Person()) // works fine
val p3: Person = identity(null) // does not work
```

Is it also possible to write a function like the one above which takes a second argument of type `V` which must not be null? I think about something like this where `arg2` can not be null:

```
fun <V: Person?> identity(arg1: V, args2: V): V
```

Not that both args should have the exact same type so `<V: Person?, W: Person>` would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you want to achieve, you could change `V`'s upper bound to something not nullable and explicitly marking it as nullable wherever needed, like this:

```
fun <V: Person> identity(nullable: V?, nonNullable: V): V? = TODO() // do something

val p1: Person? = identity(null, Person()) // works fine
val p2: Person? = identity(Person(), Person()) // works fine
val p3: Person? = identity(null, null) // does not compile as second argument is null
```

Note that however you'll need to decide whether to return a nullable or non-nullable result, while in your original example that was inferred depending on whether the actual `V` was nullable or not.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too but it's really important for me that the return value is the same as the first argument

Comment: Could you add some examples of your 2nd fun being called to clarify what you want.

Comment: @Cilenco I believe you could express that via Kotlin contracts API. I've actually tried that way but I couldn't get anything that worked, so it's either too early for such functionality or I missed something in my tests